# Returned Data from jQuery Ajax Not Displaying in Joomla Site Frontend

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla

Good day everyone.

I'm building a Joomla module that uses jquery ajax to display html data. Here's the ajax code

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "index.php?option=com_wetvmenu&task=getMenuItemHtml",
    data: {"test": "yes"},
    complete: function () {
        console.log("Process completed");
    },
    success: function (returnedData) {
        this.html = returnedData;
        console.log(this.html); // this.html contains right data
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("Error occured");
    },
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            console.log("Page not found");
        }
    }
});
console.log(this.html); // this.html contains wrong data
```

Within success anonymous function this.html contains the right data, but on the next log which is outside ajax it contains wrong data either it displays

- Wrong html e.g. Module in p tag (have no idea where module comes from) or the last content saved within it
- Empty value

The task is to ensure the html content returned from the php page can be passed outside ajax.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You can store it in a variable by declaring it outside ajax function and initialize that inside `success:` call!

Comment: Thanks Dhaval! Sorry this comment is coming late.